# Let u be harmonic, show that u*g is harmonic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, convolution, harmonic-functions

Let u be an harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and g be a distribution function with compact support. I need to show that $u*g$ is an harmonic function.

**Idea of proof**

I start by considering a function $u:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be harmonic and bounded $\Rightarrow$ u is constant.
Since $u$ is harmonic, we can use the mean value property. Let $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, then we can show that $u(a)=u(b)$ by choosing a constant $R>0$ big enough so that:
$u(j)=\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\int\int u(x,y)dxdy, \forall j\in\{a,b\}$. Then,
$u(a)-u(b)=\frac{1}{\pi R^2}(\int\int_{D(a,R)\text{\ }D(b,R)}u(x,y)dxdy-\int\int_{D(b,R)\text{\ }D(a,R)}u(x,y)dxdy)$.
Letting $R\rightarrow\infty$, $u(a)-u(b)=2M \times\{\text{smth goint to }0\}\Rightarrow u(a)=u(b)$, where $M$ is the upper bound for u.

Now, I know a result for the Poisson kernel via Laplace operator, but I don't think this is applicable in the case.
Do you have any hints?

Comment: I don't follow this at all. What does the fact that a bounded harmonic function is constant have to do with showing that $u*g$ is harmonic?

Answer (score 3):

If $g$ is an honest function for which $u*g$ is defined as a function ($C_c^\infty$, for example) then you can differentiate the convolution under the integral sign to show that $\Delta(u*g) = 0$: the point is that you can let the Laplacian attack $u$ only, which (since $u$ is harmonic) annihilates the convolution. For more general $g$ you may need to demonstrate this identity in the sense of distributions, but the strategy is the same: pass the Laplacian from the test function to $u$ via integration by parts.

Comment: it is a bit hard to follow. In this case $g$ is a distribution with compact support. Does it follow it belongs to the case you define as "honest"? Also could you please clarify a little on "pass the Laplacian from the test function to $u$ via integration by parts"?

Comment: If you have a distribution with compact support, then you will have to prove that the convolution is harmonic in the sense of distributions. $T$ is harmonic in the sense of distributions if $\langle T, \Delta \phi\rangle = 0$ for all $\phi$ in the support of $T$. To prove such an identity in this particular case, you would write out the action of $u*g$ on $\Delta\phi$, which would pair $g$ with $u*\Delta\phi$. If you integrate by parts you find $u*\Delta\phi = 0$. Once this is done, you will need to explain why $u*g$ is also a harmonic *function* instead of only a distribution.

Comment: what do you think about the following: $\forall \phi <g∗u,\Delta\phi>=<g,u∗\Delta\phi>=<g,\Delta u∗\phi>=0$ because $\Delta u=0$. This would prove that $u∗g$ is harmonic. The crucial thing, however, would be to prove that $u∗\Delta\phi=\Delta u∗\phi$.  Any ideas on how to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Say $S\subset\Bbb R^n$ is the unit sphere, and let $\sigma$ be normalized "surface area" on $S$ (so $\sigma$ is the unique rotation-invariant Borel probability measure on $S$.) Recall that $v:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb C$ is harmonic if and only if $v$ is continuous and $$v(x)=\int_Sv(x+t\xi)\,d\sigma(\xi)\quad(x\in\Bbb R^n, r>0).$$